# Limiting Integer Value Between 1 and 100 in grails

Tags: grails

i want to do something like that an integer whose value will be always between 1 and 100 how to achieve this and where can i get the list of all Grails data types

```
Integer profileCompletion

static constraints = {
    profileCompletion()
}
```

Comment: thanks beg your pardon. Next time i will do so.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is easily found in the Grails documentation: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest

Comment: please dont down vote me i will be alert next time sorry friend please   help me to ask questions your down vote not allowing me to ask questions please..

Comment: This site isn't intended to replace google.  I'd suggest spending at least 5-10 minutes googleing before asking your question here.  I'm not trying to be mean, just trying to help you understand when to ask questions.  I'd also read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: thanks friend i have already apologized for my nuisance i will follow you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search for the use of constraints would've given you the correct answer:

From [constraints documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) you can read:

> `range`   Uses a Groovy range to ensure that a property's value occurs within a specified range

```
profileCompletion(range: 1..100)
```

Comment: thank for your instant reply sorry for troubling you but i feel this site is more faster than google